# Add prefix for logs lines log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I have class where write logs, i used log4net:

```
class MyClass
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

        public void Work(int i)
        {
            _logger.Info($"{i} start");
            _logger.Info($"{i} work");
            _logger.Info($"{i} finished");
        }
    }
```

logs worked. But how can changing this code, that prefix `"{i}"` set before of writing block of logs and do not need to add each time when write to log? Something likes this:

```
using(_logs.Startprefix("{i}"))
{
  _logger.Info("start");
  _logger.Info("work");
  _logger.Info("finished");
}
```

as result in file will be write in each line `{i}`

Comment: can you just add another line just showing the prefix at the beginning of the method. _logger.Info("{i}"); ?

Comment: i need `"{i}"` in each line of log, when log.Info, log.Warn or so on called. I do not want write prefix in each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found standart for this case. `LogicalThreadContext` for log4net, and my problem is solved like this:

```
using (LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push($"{i}"))
{
  _logger.Info("start");
  _logger.Info("work");
  _logger.Info("finished");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your own logger that incapsulates `ILog` and implement `Prefix` member there.

```
    class MyLogger 
    {
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        public int? Prefix;

        public MyLogger(Type t)
        {
            _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(t.Name);
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            _logger.Info($"{Prefix?.ToString() ?? ""} {message}");
        }

    }
```

Then you may use `using` statement:

```
using (myLogger.Prefix = i)
{
  myLogger.Info("start");
  myLogger.Info("work");
  myLogger.Info("finished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not a built in feature of log4net. You would need to write a wrapper around the log4net logic to add this functionality. Something like this, but this is a rough draft, you would need to fix it up and complete it.

```
class MyLogger
{
  private readonly string _prefix;
  private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

  public MyLogger(string prefix)
  {
    _prefix = prefix;
  }

  public void Info(string info)
  {
    _logger.Info($"{_prefix} {info}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest part would be to use a new method like this and a property for your prefix:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

    public int Prefix {get;set;}

    public void Work()
    {
        PrintLine("start");
        PrintLine("work");
        PrintLine("finished");
    }

    private void PrintLine(string txt) {
        _logger.Info(Prefix + " " + txt);
    }

}
```